# Why is my code not removing the country border from leaflet map?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, leaflet

I have written a function to draw a border around a selected country / country of user location, it works fine but when a new country is selected it just add another border to the country selected without removing the previous one:

```js
function border1(countryCode) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "libs/php/countryBorders.php",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",

    success: function (result) {
      //remove draw layer

      if (result.status.name == "ok") {
        // if (mymap.hasLayer(border)) {
        //     mymap.removeLayer(border);
        //   };

        filterData = result.data.border.features.filter(
          (a) => a.properties.iso_a2 === countryCode
        );

        border = L.geoJSON(filterData[0]);
        mymap.fitBounds(border.getBounds());

        //call layer function
        layer();
      }
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
    },
  });
}

const layer = () => {
  L.geoJSON(filterData, {
    style: function (feature) {
      return {
        color: "blue",
        fillOpacity: 0,
        stroke: true,
      };
    },
  }).addTo(mymap);
};
```

The code works as described above when I comment out

```
if (mymap.hasLayer(border)) {
    mymap.removeLayer(border);
};
```

however when this code is uncommented - it draws no border at all and inspect shows the error:

```
"leaflet.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search
for '_leaflet_id' in undefined
    at h (leaflet.js:5:662)
    at i.hasLayer (leaflet.js:5:65679)
    at Object.success (scripts.js:238:27)
    at fire (jquery-3.6.0.js:3500:31)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.6.0.js:3630:7)
    at done (jquery-3.6.0.js:9796:14)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.6.0.js:10057:9)"
```

both `var border;` and `var filterData;` are declared in global scope.

Please help

Comment: What's the value of `border` when the error is triggered? Is it `undefined`?

Comment: Yes it is, I just did a console.log of border where that if statement is and on the first time a country is selected the log shows it as undefined, however the second time it has value but when the if statement is uncommented it dosent draw the border at all no matter how many times you select a different country?

Comment: Pay attention to https://leafletjs.com/reference#map-haslayer - the `hasLayer` method expects an instance of `L.Layer`, and not `undefined`.

Comment: ok well I tried " if (typeof border !== 'undefined') {
                    if (mymap.hasLayer(border)) {
                     mymap.removeLayer(border);
                   }}; " but it now dosen't remove the borders again however its working the same as if I had the original if statement commented out, have I used the typeof function correctly?